# «Цигель, цигель, ай лю-лю!»

Tags: этимология, фразеология, переводы

«Цигель, цигель, ай лю-лю!»
Интересно, что это значит в переводе, и часто ли используется в разговорной речи?

Comment: Тоже всегда был очень интересен этот вопрос, выражение часто использовалось в военных фильмах времен второй мировой, думал заимствовано из немецкого или из польского. Но ни немцы ни поляки понятия не имеют о таком выражении)) кирпич из немецкого по смыслу как-то не подходит

Answer (score 3):

Фраза в разговорной речи используется как универсальный побудитель к действию.

Интересный факт:// Даль В.И. Толковый словарь живого великорусского языка. В 4-х тт. - М.: ТЕРРА, 1994. - Т.4: "P-V" - С. 574.
Цигéльня ж. юж. зап. нем. кирпичный завод. Цигель пск. кирпич.

Comment: >Цигель пск. кирпич.
Это слово (в значении "кирпич") происходит, по-видимому, от немецкого *Ziegel* (цигл). 

Германия до середины ХХ века была одной из самых развитых технически стран в мире. Поэтому, начиная ещё с времён царя Петра I, многие технические термины заимствовались именно из немецкого языка. Как сейчас заимствуются из американского английского.

Слово *кирпич* в современном литературном украинском -- *цегла*. Белорус. *цэгла*, польск. *cegła*, чешск. *cihla*.